# Ajax function not working properly for delete and update comments

Tags: node.js, ajax

I'm using Ajax in a comments section in my blog project. It was working fine however clearly I've changed something because now when I go to edit a comment it won't work and when I try to delete, it does destroy the comment but it also gets rid of a load of other comments until I refresh the page when everything looks fine. The only Ajax function now working is create new comment.

Here's my show page code for my comments section:

```
<!--================== COMMENTS DISPLAY SECTION ====================================================================-->
<div id="comments">
    <% blog.comments.forEach(function(comment){ %>
    <div class="comment-container">
        <div class="jumbotron comment">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <img class="comment-ico" src = "<%=comment.author.image%>">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <h4><%=comment.author.username%></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div><p><%=comment.text%></p></div>

<!--=================EDIT COMMENT FORM =========================================================================-->
       <form id="edit-comment-form" action = "/blogs/<%= blog._id %>/comments/<%=comment._id%>?_method=PUT" method = "POST" id="newComment">
            <textarea class = "form-control" rows="4" name = "comment[text]"><%=comment.text%></textarea>
            <button class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
        </form>

<!--==================================================================================================================-->

        <!-- if current user is the same as author -->

        <% if(currentUser && currentUser.username == comment.author.username) { %>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1 choice">
                    <a class="edit">Edit</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <form id = "delete-form" action = "/blogs/<%= blog._id %>/comments/<%=comment._id%>?_method=DELETE" method = "POST">
                    <input type = "submit" class = "button-delete" value = "Delete"></form>
                </div>
                <% } %>
                <% if(currentUser && currentUser.username == comment.author.username) { %>
                <div class="col-md-1 choice-report">
                    <a class="report">Report</a>
                </div>
                <% } else { %>
                <div class="col-md-1 choice-no-user">
                    <a href="/blogs/<%=blog._id%>/comments/<%=comment._id%>/report" class="report">Report</a>
                </div>
                <% } %>

            </div>
        <br>
        <hr class = "style-three">
        <% }) %>
    </div>

</div>
</div>

<!--==================================================================================================================-->




<% if(currentUser){ %>
<div class = "container-form">
   <form action = "/blogs/<%= blog._id %>/comments" method = "POST" id="newComment">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img class="newComment-ico" src = " <%=currentUser.image%>">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <label for="comment">Add comment</label>
        </div>
    </div>
        <textarea class = "form-control" rows="4" placeholder = "Type comment here..." name = "comment[text]"></textarea>
        <button class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

<% } %>
```

And my Ajax code:

```
// update comment
$('#comments').on('submit', '#edit-comment-form', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
// get info from form
var formData = $(this).serialize();
var formAction = $(this).attr('action');
var $originalItem = $(this).parent('.comment-container');
$.ajax({
    url: formAction,
    data: formData,
    type: 'PUT',
    originalItem: $originalItem,
    success: function(data) {
        var blog_id = location.pathname.replace("/blogs/", "");
        this.originalItem.html(
            `
          <div class="comment-container">
        <div class="jumbotron comment">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <img class="comment-ico" src = "${data.author.image}">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <h4>${data.author.username}</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div><p>${data.text}</p></div>

       <form id="edit-comment-form" action = "/blogs/${blog._id}/comments/${data._id}?_method=PUT" method = "POST" id="newComment">
            <textarea class = "form-control" rows="4" name = "comment[text]">${data.text}</textarea>
            <button class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
        </form>


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1 choice">
                    <a class="edit">Edit</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <form id = "delete-form" action = "/blogs/${blog._id}/comments/${data._id}?_method=DELETE" method = "POST">
                    <input type = "submit" class = "button-delete" value = "Delete"></form>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-1 choice-report">
                    <a class="report">Report</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <br>
        <hr class = "style-three">
            `
            );
    }
});
});
```

And here's the update comments route:

```
// comment update route
router.put("/:comment_id", function(req, res){
Comment.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.comment_id, req.body.comment,  {new: true}, function(err, updatedComment){
    if(err) {
        res.redirect("back");
    } else {
        if(req.xhr);
            res.json(updatedComment);
        // } else {
        // res.redirect("/blogs/" + req.params.id);
        // }
    }
})
})
```

My destroy Ajax code:

```
// delete comments asynchonously
$('#comments').on('submit', '#delete-form', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var confirmResponse = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this comment?');
if(confirmResponse){
    var actionURL = $(this).attr('action');
    $itemToDelete = $(this).closest('.comment-container');
    $.ajax({
        url: actionURL,
        type: 'DELETE',
        itemToDelete: $itemToDelete,
        success: function(data){
            this.itemToDelete.remove();
        }
    })
} else {
    $(this).find('input').blur();
}
})
```

And destroy route:

```
// comments destroy route
router.delete("/:comment_id", function(req, res){
Comment.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.comment_id, function(err, comment){
    if(err) {
        res.redirect("back");
    } else {
        res.json(comment);
    }
})
})
```

UPDATE:

I noticed a couple of errors on my Ajax code whereby I had referenced ${blog._id} rather than ${blog_id}. I've updated as follows:

```
// update comment
$('#comments').on('submit', '#edit-comment-form', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
// get info from form
var formData = $(this).serialize();
var formAction = $(this).attr('action');
var $originalItem = $(this).parent('.comment-container');
$.ajax({
    url: formAction,
    data: formData,
    type: 'PUT',
    originalItem: $originalItem,
    success: function(data) {
        var blog_id = location.pathname.replace("/blogs/", "");
        this.originalItem.html(
            `
            <div class="jumbotron comment">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <img class="comment-ico" src = "${data.author.image}">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <h4>${data.author.username}</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div><p>${data.text}</p></div>

       <form id="edit-comment-form" action = "/blogs/${blog_id}/comments/${data._id} method = "POST" id="newComment">
            <textarea class = "form-control" rows="4" name = "comment[text]">${data.text}</textarea>
            <button class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
        </form>


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1 choice">
                    <a class="edit">Edit</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <form id = "delete-form" action = "/blogs/${blog_id}/comments/${data._id}?_method=DELETE" method = "POST">
                    <input type = "submit" class = "button-delete" value = "Delete"></form>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-1 choice-report">
                    <a class="report">Report</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <br>
        <hr class = "style-three">
            `
            );
    }
});
});
```

Now the comment will update asynchronously, however until the page is refreshed, again it's kicking off a load of other comments.Essentially it's getting rid temporarily of all comments beneath the one being edited. When you refresh though, all comments re-appear in the correct order including the edits made to the comment in question

Comment: You have duplicate ids `delete-form`. Use class instead.

Comment: Sorry where are you seeing the duplicate? I have delete-form in the show page and then refer to #delete-form in my Ajax but I can't see a duplicate? Also this doesn't explain the issue with the update function

Comment: You are rendering `<form id = "delete-form"` inside forEach loop. If you have more than 1 comment you'd have duplicate ids.